# Method that imports things

Tags: java, methods, import

Is it possible to make a method in java that can import things? If so how is it done? If you are wondering why I am asking this, it is because I am making a library in java to make your code smaller.

Comment: If you mean a tool that resolves missing imports from a `.java` file then you can. If you mean something that imports from you given a compiled java code then you can't, as code without proper imports will not even compile.

Comment: No. `import`s are done on the `class` level. `import` whatever you need in your method in the class containing it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That was all I was wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Java. You have to import the resources (classes, interfaces, enums, `static` imports, etc.) in each file. At most, you can use less code by importing all the public classes and interfaces that belong to a package by using `*` wildcard. Example:

```
//Importing all classes and interfaces declared ad java.util package
import java.util.*;
```